# Is there any toy example that can exemplify the performance of double Q-learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, double-q-learning

I recently tried to reproduce the results of [double Q-learning](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2010/file/091d584fced301b442654dd8c23b3fc9-Paper.pdf). However, the results are not satisfying. I have also tried to compare double Q learning with Q-learning in Taxi-v3, FrozenLake without slippery, Roulette-v0, etc. But Q-learning outperforms double Q-learning in all of these environments.

I am not sure whether if there is something wrong with my implementation as many materials about double Q actually focus on double DQN. While at the same time of checking, I wonder is there any toy example that can exemplify the performance of double Q-learning?

Comment: Have you used the same parameters and hyper-parameters as the ones in [the paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2010/file/091d584fced301b442654dd8c23b3fc9-Paper.pdf) for the roulette environment?

Comment: @nbro Thanks for your comment. I haven't tested that in the paper's roulette as I am not very understand the environment settings. Consider giving it a try another day.

Comment: have you seen the example from the Sutton and Barto book?

Comment: @DavidIreland Haven't yet. Thanks for suggestion.